# How to query keycloak resource permission with a token issued from a public client

Tags: node.js, security, keycloak

I have a Front End Javascript client that is protected by keycloak. The Keycloak client for the Front End App is of type `Public` and called `blog_gui`.

I also have an API that is protected by a `Confidential` client called 'blog_api', with `Authorization` Enabled.

When I make a request from my Front End App to the API, I send the JWT issued by keycloak from the `public` client (blog_gui) as a Bearer token in the header of the request.

In the API I want to check if the Front End App that sent the JWT has permission to a specific resource. So I send a request to the keycloak server at the following URL, including the JWT from the Front End App as a Bearer token

```
http://${host}:${post}/auth/realms/${realm}/authz/protection/uma-policy
```

The result I get back from keycloak is

```
{
    "error": "invalid_clientId",
    "error_description": "Client application [blog_gui] is not registered as a resource server."
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the full request you are sending to Keycloak including headers and payload?

Comment: @sventorben I login using the keycloak-js adapter in my frontend JS App. The adapter does all the communication with Keycloak for me. From the response I get back from keycloak-js, I take the token and use it with the GET request described in my question. That GET request includes an Authorization header with the value `Bearer <token from keycloak>`

Comment: Is your frontend and backend mapped to the same client in Keycloak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your scenario keycloak-js will query Keycloak for an access token with an audience/client `blog_gui`. This client is public, so it is not a registered resource server.
You may want to execute a [token exchange](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_token-exchange) to obtain an access token for your backend client (`blog_api`) and use the obtained token to query the uma-policy endpoint. You can find additional info on how to query the endpoint in the [Authorization Services docs over here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_protection_permission_api_papi).

Make sure that your `blog_api` client is confidential and has `Authorization Enabled` switched on. You may refer to [this documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/14.0/authorization_services/#_resource_server_overview) on how to setup the client accordingly.