# keycloak-js How to authenticate AND authorize users

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to link together authenticating and authorizing users in my frontend using `Keycloak` and the `keycloak-js` adapter.

**To preface this: I know that the `keycloak-js` adapter requires the client to have `public` as the Access Type.**

My main question is how can I use `Keycloak` authentication AND authorization via the same client. If the Access Type MUST be set to `public` for the `keycloak-js` adapter to work, then how can I restrict access to my API depending on the users permissions?

Will I need two clients for this? One for authentication and one for authorization? If so, how can I use the access token from the authentication client in the authorization client?

My current setup in Keycloak is as follows:

- Realm: `admin-service`
- Client: `admin-service-api`

  - Access Type: `confidential` (because I want to use authorization to restrict api requests according to permission levels)
  - Root URL: `http://localhost:8080/`
  - Valid Redirect URIs: `http://localhost:8080/*`
- Roles:

  - `admin`
- Users:

  - `test-user`

My authorization setup for `admin-service-api` is as follows:

- Resources: `Books Resource`

  - Uri (these are my API endpoints):

    - `/v1/books`
    - `/v1/books/{id}`
  - Scopes:

    - `books:delete`
    - `books:create`
    - `books:update`
    - `books:read`
- Policies:

  - Default Policy
  - Books Policy:

    - Realm roles:

      - admin (the required checkbox is not checked)
- Permissions:

  - Default Permission
  - Books Resource Permission:

    - Resources: `Books Resource`
    - Apply Policy: `Books Policy`

So with this setup, I have restricted my API (which is written in GoLang) to only allow requests if the requesting user has the appropriate permissions by making a request to the Keycloak API via `https://my.auth.server/auth/realms/{{realm_name}}/protocol/openid-connect/token` to retrieve the users access token and a list of the users permissions.

From there I can use this access token to make requests to my API to create/read/update/delete books so long as my `test-user` has the `admin` role. If my user does not have the `admin` role, the user is presented with an unauthorized message (401).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68498168/631612